# How to get the next sibling in addEventListener using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to get the next sibling of the element which is clicked, and I'm using typescript. Here is my code.

```
let jobRowList = document.getElementsByClassName('job-item');
for(let i = 0; i < jobRowList.length; i++) {
  // add event listener for each element with class name job-item
  let jobRow = jobRowList.item(i);
  jobRow.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    console.log(this.nextSibling); // error
  });
}
```

However, since `this` is an `Element` instead of `HTMLElement`, it doesn't have a property called `nextSibling`, so typescript throws an error here.

```
TS2339: Property 'nextSibling' does not exist on type 'JobListTable'.
```

Is there any way to get the nextSibling of the clicked element using typescript?

Comment: Try `ev.target.nextSibling`

Comment: `ev.target` could be a descendant of the bound element, I'd suggest `ev.currentTarget` instead, or just stop using Typescript.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia it doesn't work either. `EventTarget` doesn't have a property called `nextSibling`

Comment: Did you try just removing the arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the arrow function doesn't refer to the clicked element. You could potentially remove the arrow function and use a normal function instead - however with the arrow, you are probably looking for

```
ev.currentTarget.nextElementSibling
```

---

```
jobRow.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    console.log(ev.currentTarget.nextElementSibling); 
});
```